# Why is Oracle so much slower for small atomic inserts compared to Postgres? And what defaults can I change to remedy this?

Tags: oracle, performance

If I create a brand new database from a Docker image and run a fresh database with the default settings.

```
CREATE TABLE "TEST_TABLE" ( 
    "ID" VARCHAR2(32 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "CREATED" TIMESTAMP (6) DEFAULT NULL NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "REFERENCE" NVARCHAR2(500),
    PRIMARY KEY(ID)
);
```

This insert statement takes between 15ms and 30ms to complete (after being run a couple of times).

```
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES ('1', '10-SEP-02 14.10.10.123000000', 'hello world');
```

However if I run the same query in Postgres it takes 2-3ms to complete (after being run a couple of times).

What defaults in Oracle cause such poor insert performance?

Comment: It's going to be something in your setup or your testing methodology.  Any RDBMS can perform a single-row insert in much less than a ms.

Comment: I agree that it is an issue with your config or methodology, and not anything inherent in the database.  If it _were_ inherent in the databse (as your question implies) then Oracle would not have such a dominant position in the market.

Comment: Aside from your question, your INSERT is trying to insert a _string_ into a TIMESTAMP column.  This forces oracle to perform a TO_TIMESTAMP function to convert the string representation of a timestamp into the binary format that oracle actually uses to store the timestamp.  And given your default value of NLS_TIMETAMP_FORMAT, this has a high risk of throwning an error.  You should always explicitly use the TO_TIMESTAMP or TO_DATE function (as appropriate).  Also, it's been over 20 years since the entire IT world was busting butt resolve Y2K.  Please don't recreate the problem.

Comment: Hey, I don’t think oracle is slow, it’s just some of the defaults perform really poorly.  Perhaps the slowness is specifically my system. Don’t worry about the lack of a `to_timestamp` function, I only removed it to reduce the noise in the example.

Answer (score 2):

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE "TEST_TABLE" ( 
    "ID" VARCHAR2(32 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "CREATED" TIMESTAMP (6) DEFAULT NULL NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "REFERENCE" NVARCHAR2(500),
    PRIMARY KEY(ID)
);

Table created.

SQL>

SQL> set timing on
SQL> INSERT INTO test_table VALUES ('1', systimestamp, 'hello world');

1 row created.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00

SQL> select executions, elapsed_time from v$sql where sql_text = 'INSERT INTO test_table VALUES (''1'', systimestamp, ''hello world'')';

EXECUTIONS ELAPSED_TIME
---------- ------------
         1         1121

Elapsed: 00:00:00.09
SQL>
```

The insert took 1121 microseconds = 1.121 milliseconds, on the first try, with default settings.

```
SQL> INSERT INTO test_table VALUES ('2', systimestamp, 'hello world');

1 row created.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
SQL> select executions, elapsed_time from v$sql where sql_text = 'INSERT INTO test_table VALUES (''2'', systimestamp, ''hello world'')';

EXECUTIONS ELAPSED_TIME
---------- ------------
         1          780

Elapsed: 00:00:00.09
```

Even quicker on additional attempts.

Problem is not with the database, but the software/hardware environment around it.